Which replacement kit works with my Broan 660 exhaust fan housing?
Anyone able to identify which Broan kit can replace this model bathroom fan for upgrade? I only see the 670s available as an upgradeable.


Is this the Broan-Nutone 660 with the light between the dual grates? https://www.borderstates.com/All-Products/Heating-Ventilation-Cooling/Ventilation/Fans/Bath-Ventilation-Fans/Broan-Nutone-660-Series-Heat-Ventilation-Light-Combination-Bath-Exhaust-Fans/Broan-Nutone-660-Series-Heat-Ventilation-Light-Combination-Bath-Exhaust-Fans-1300-W-70-CFM/p/150716

If you cannot find an exact replacement for models 664, 665 or 666, you have a few options:

Often, the fan motor is simply clogged with rust and dust.

Remove the fan assembly from the fixture.
Disassemble the motor (likely requires removal of just two bolts).
Clean gently with toothbrush and naphtha, removing hardened grease and gunk. This is best done outdoors, and avoid any source of ignition -- naphtha is flammable!
Let dry thoroughly for a few days.
Lubricate motor shaft and felt absorbent pads with ordinary auto motor oil.
Reassemble, and it should work for years.


Another option is to disassemble the fan from motor and use a "universal" replacement motor. You might have trouble finding one the right size, with the correct hole spacing, though.

Finally, a bit more work: replace the whole housing and fan assembly (likely not much more expensive than fan motor alone). That also gives the option of putting in a more modern fan, perhaps with light and infrared heat lamp. It also might involve a bit of carpentry and wallboard cutting.



Unfortunately I'm fairly sure the bearings are starting to wear down on the unit if the sounds i'm hearing lately are any indicator. Amazon and repair clinic are letdowns for this unit model series; i may have to just opt for a full out and in - that said  > https://i.imgur.com/8pjq0kw.jpeg, does the stuff on the left of the metal casing appear to be insulation or you think thats just accumulated dust in between the casing and drywall?

Hard to tell from photo -- could be blown-in cellulose insulation or drywall. Poke it -- if it's soft, it's insulation.
